# Inconsistent TCP Keep-Alive Frequency

Tags: .net, windows, sockets, tcp, wireshark

I've configured a TCP socket in a .NET application to send Keep-Alive packets every 15 minutes. Note that in the .NET world, it's only possible to manipulate this parameter (as opposed to simply *enabling* Keep-Alives) using the low-level `Socket.IOControl` API to pass in bytes representing a native struct.

Observe a Wireshark capture of outgoing Keep-Alives below:

[image: Wireshark Capture]

Everything went as planned between 12:35 and 14:05 (Keep-Alives were sent every 15 minutes), but after that, the frequency with which these packets were sent began to vary wildly (24 minutes, 15 minutes, 29 minutes, 1 hour 4 minutes). The application was behaving completely as expected during this period with the exception of this inconsistency.

Shortly after this period, the Keep-Alive span reverted to 15 minutes again.

---

FYI, the code I've written to set the parameter is as below:

```
private void SetKeepAlive(uint time, uint interval, SocketOptionLevel level)
{
    // The native structure for this is defined in mstcpip.h as:
    //struct tcp_keepalive {
    //u_long onoff;
    //u_long keepalivetime;
    //u_long keepaliveinterval;
    //};

    var inValue = new[] { Convert.ToUInt32(true), time, interval }
                    .SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes)
                    .ToArray();

    var outValue = new byte[sizeof(uint)];

    Socket.SetSocketOption(level, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
    Socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, inValue, outValue);
 }
```

...called with the equivalent of:

```
SetKeepAlive(900000, 1000, SocketOptionLevel.Socket);
```

---

The purpose of these Keep-Alives is to prevent some of our network hardware from dropping the connection after a timeout (around 30 minutes), so we can't afford for these intervals to vary so wildly. It's also a bit of a pain for us to build in application-level heart-beating and other such user-land solutions - too many systems would need to change.

**What could be causing this inconsistent behaviour?**

Comment: Was the connection idle all the time? The usage of keep-alive is to have a regular exchange of packets. If this is already realized by exchanging application data no keep-alives will be sent, that is the timer is reset whenever application data get exchanged.

Comment: Are keep-alives suppressed (i.e. the timer is reset) if regular datagrams have been sent in the interim? That would make sense logically, but I was under the impression (can't remember why) that that wasn't the case.

Comment: Yes, keep-alives are only used to fill the idle time. If there is nothing idle then there is no need for keep-alives. TCP is a very smart protocol :)

Comment: Thanks, Steffen. Do you have any docs on that? That does make complete sense but the few resources I've read on the net are ambiguous on this point. I assume that this 'optimization' would be implementation-dependent and not mandated by the standard.

Comment: I've put the details into the answer.

Comment: @Ani: The TCP specification (RFC 1122 section 4.2.3.6): `Keep-alive packets MUST only be sent when no data or acknowledgement packets have been received for the connection within an interval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From RFC 1122 [section 4.2.3.6](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1122/114.htm):

> Keep-alive packets MUST only be sent when no data or acknowledgement packets have been received for the connection within an interval.

This means, if that in your case a keep-alive packet will be sent 15 minutes after the last data packet was sent or received by your application. It will only be sent every 15 minutes if your application is idle.